Connect refused between docker containers
Development Environment: MacOS
I'm trying to build a microservices application using golang which requires communication between containers. I have 2 services, service-2 on port 8080 and service-1 running on port 8084.
I'm getting connection refused while calling service-2 from service-1. PFB the error
2024/05/11 10:09:41 An error occured in handler Get "http://service-2:8080/buy": dial tcp 172.22.0.2:8080: connect: connection refused
2024/05/11 10:09:41 http: panic serving 192.168.65.1:17072: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

PFB docker-compose.yml for reference
name: microservices

services:
  service-2:
    build:
      context: ./service-2
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8443"
    restart: always
  service-1:
    build:
      context: ./service-1
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8084:8443"
    restart: always


I've searched and trying out different solutions from stackoverflow but none of them worked. Appreciate your help.

The error you're seeing is likely due to the fact that your service-2 container is not listening on port 8080. In your docker-compose.yml file, you have mapped port 8080 of the host machine to port 8443 of the service-2 container. This means that when you try to access service-2 on port 8080, it will actually try to connect to port 8443 inside the container.
To fix this, you need to make sure that service-2 is listening on port 8443 and not on port 8080. You can do this by changing the port mapping in your docker-compose.yml file or by updating the code in service-2 to listen on port 8443 instead of 8080.

Thanks man! You're a lifesaver. I was banging my head since 3 days to figure this out
